# upload a new php extestion with WHM

Tags: php, php-extension, whm

I need to load and run a new extension on an apache/linux server

I have downloaded the extension from the vendor website and they say to upload to:

```
/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/
```

How can I upload to that path via whm?  (I have no ssh access and I don't know how to use ssh).

Comment: "i dont know how to use ssh"  Then you probably shouldn't be messing with extensions.

Comment: thanks - but keep the comments constructive

Answer (score 0):

Follow thsese steps.

Web Browser => WHM login >> Main >> Software >> Apache Update
Console => From the console execute /scripts/easyapache

Go through each step as follows.

1. Click “start customizing based on profile”
2. Select Apache Version – Click Next to proceed with the current version.
3. Select PHP Major Version – Click Next to proceed with the current version.
4. Select PHP Minor version – Click Next to proceed with the current version.
5. Short option list – Click Exhaustive Options List to view full options.
6. Exhaustive Options List – From here you can select the PHP modules you needed
7. Click Save & Build to start apache-php compilation.

Comment: thats great thanks but it does not tell me how to upload the extension ?

Comment: All PHP modules will be available there...Just select that & install..No need to uload

Comment: if you read my initial post - im talking about a 3rd party extension so it will not be there !

Comment: Fine. Usually files are being uploaded using  ftp account. If you have whm access then you can create one.Then upload those files.

Comment: problem with that is the ftp accounts are limited to the /home/ folder which is well above where i need to access !

Comment: connect as root user...You can access all directories.